# Issue with @WebServiceRef not being invoked in migration from SpringBoot 2 to 3

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am migrating code from SpringBoot 2 to 3. This code was working in 2 but not in 3.

```java
@Configuration
public class MyBeansProducer
{
   @Bean
   public MyDAO createDAO()
   {
      return new MyDAO();
   }
}
```

```java
public class MyDAO
{
   @WebServiceRef(WSMyInterfaceHttpService.class)
   public void setRef(Ref wsRef )
   {
      this.wsRef = wsRef ;
   }
}
```

Problem is that `setRef` is never invoked.

I have found this code in Spring 5 that used to make this work:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/5.3.x/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/context/annotation/CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java#L406

Is this no longer supported? How can achieve same thing with SpringBoot 3?

## Workaround

I configure it manually for now.

```java
   @Bean
   public MyDAO createDAO()
   {
     WSMyInterfaceHttpService httpService = new WSMyInterfaceHttpService();
     MyInterface wsRef = httpService.getWSMyInterfaceHttpPort();
      
      MyDAO it = new MyDAO();
      it.setWsRef(wsRef);
      return it;
   }
```

Edit: Issue on Github https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/31524

Answer (score 0):

Got an answer [on Github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/31524#issuecomment-1785786110)

> I am afraid this is to be expected. JAX-WS support has been removed in Spring Framework 6, see #27422, and the now upgraded Upgrading to Spring Framework 6.x wiki page.